# Downloading in background and waking app when finished

Tags: swift, background-process, download, urlsession

I use URLSession configured as background session to download some files. When download finishes I use:

```
func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didFinishDownloadingTo location: URL)
```

to move downloaded file. Everything works fine, except that when app is in the background this function is not being called. It's called right after app is restored to foreground, but I would like the system to wake my app after file is downloaded. Is there some way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is indeed :)

You probably need to change a few things in your setup.

First the `URLSessionConfiguration` you use should be of type `background` like so:

```
URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: "your.unique.id.here")
```

Then, in your `AppDelegate` you need to implement this method:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession identifier: String, completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void)
```

Where you do something like store the `completionHandler` so it can be used later on.

And finally, where you normally do your "done downloading" magic... typically here:

```
 func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didFinishDownloadingTo location: URL)
```

You need to check for the presence of a `completionHandler` and if present, invoke that.

#### Example

The last two bits of the above may seem a bit...huh?? so here is an example.

In your `AppDelegate` you can define an optional for the `completionHandler` so you can store it for later on:

```
var backgroundSessionCompletionHandler: (() -> Void)?
```

and the method then looks like this:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession identifier: String, completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    if identifier == "your.unique.id.here" {
        backgroundSessionCompletionHandler = completionHandler
    }
}
```

And then you "just" need to call that once you are done processing the downloaded file, which you can do like this:

```
if  let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate,
    let completionHandler = appDelegate.backgroundSessionCompletionHandler {
        appDelegate.backgroundSessionCompletionHandler = nil
        OperationQueue.main.addOperation {
            completionHandler()
        }
    }
```

Also, take a look at [this tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/110458/nsurlsession-tutorial-getting-started) for instance.

Hope that helps you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It turned out that everything already works, but not in simulator, when I test on a device it's working as expected. Also I don't really use handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession function, because after every app launching I'm just creating object that creates session with the same identifier and have its delegate implemented. Seems to work for every case, but I'm not 100% sure if this approach will work. Will test and see.

Comment: ah yes...you're right, it doesn't work as expected in the simulator, I forgot about that, sorry. Glad you got it working and good luck onwards :)